# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I need to use spring-core with version 3.2.xsd. So, I declare following in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context
>   initialization failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777)
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156)
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
>           at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

I checked that it needs spring-core with version 4.1 and higher. Is there a way to check where this is being referenced (in some other dependency maybe) and resolve the issue with 3.2.9.RELEASE ?

Notes: spring-beans, spring-context etc. are declared with version 3.2.9.RELEASE. 
mvn-dependency:tree doesn't show any other version for spring-core.

Comment: check "mvn tree"

Comment: mvn tree shows a spring-core  3.2.9.RELEASE.                                                   [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.9.RELEASE:compile

Comment: Well clearly those spring-beans 4.3.9 are not 3.2.9

Comment: The 3.2 xsd are perfectly useable with a 4.x jar.